# Php, file_put_content doen't return error but do nothing

Tags: php, file

I want open (or create if its not existing) a simple text file and append text.

I tried :

```
$res = file_put_contents("/tmp/file.log", "foo", FILE_APPEND);
echo $res;
```

The echo display '3' (3 characters I suppose). But no file is created. Then I test after create manually the file.log in my /tmp directory, the echo still display the value '4', but, from my shell if I want show the content of the file, the content is always empty (cat /tmp/file.log).

I check the permissions of the tmp directory (its 777). And when I created manually my log file, I set it permission to 777 (chmod 777 ...)

I don't find where is the problem !

Comment: I wonder why it's returning `4` when you only wrote 3 characters.

Comment: sorry, bad copy/parse x)

Comment: Are you sure `cat` didn't print anything? It will be on the same line as your prompt, since you didn't end the file with a newline.

Comment: `file_put_contents` returns the number of **bytes written**.  If it echo's 4, then that means you wrote 4 bytes.  The file **clearly exists**, and has written `foo` to it.  Are you sure you're running `cat` properly?  What do you see if you `vi /tmp/file.log`?

Comment: Yes, and file have 0 octet ( ll /tmp/file.log)

Comment: Houuu, when I search the file (via find), I find the log file in "/tmp/systemd-private-35568333d2b84d93ad7eaf502420d771-apache2.service-lWASm8/tmp/file.log", maybe a apache settings issue ? Ill look that , but I don't understand why php write in another directory instead the /tmp/file.log ...

Comment: It looks like your Apache is running in a chroot jail, to prevent it from accessing the regular filesystem hierarchy. This is probably a `systemd` setting.

Comment: Maybe you're using `systemd-nspawn`, which is like `chroot()`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is with the Apache configuration, not PHP.